# what is the best way to group in map

Tags: java, java-stream

```
transactionId|age|amount|accType|
0000000000001|1  |1.0000|saving |
0000000000002|1  |1.0000|saving |
0000000000003|1  |1.0000|current|
```

How do I loop and group them by acc type using stream?

I want to have a map like below:

```
saving: [{0000000000001|1.0000|saving}, {0000000000002|1.0000|saving}]
current: [{0000000000003|1.0000|current}]
```

Currently I am doing the filtering without grouping:

```
txs.stream().filter(x -> x.getAge().equal(1)).filter(x -> x.getAmount().equals(1.0000)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I am trying:

```
Map<String, List<TX>> tx = txs.stream()
                                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(p -> p.getAccountType()), Collectors.filtering(?))
```

How do I do multiple fitering?

Comment: Why not filter before collecting? 
`Map<String, List<TX>> tx = txs.stream()
                                .filter(x -> x.getAge().equal(1))
                                .filter(x -> x.getAmount().equals(1.0000))
                                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(p -> p.getAccountType()));`

Comment: Also, getAmount().equals(1.00) seems not very accurate. You should probably consider using BigDecimal instead of floats (with apt. rounding) for the accuracy of currency handling.